# Dynamically allocate memory for struct items

Tags: c, arrays, struct, dynamic-memory-allocation

Hi people I have a question, 
How would I go about correctly allocating memory for my struct items, 
I get two errors : Invalid application of ‘sizeof’ to incomplete type ‘struct Car'
and ‘numberCar’ undeclared (first use in this function). Can't seem to find the root of the issue here...

```
typedef struct {
    int numberCar;
    int carStatus;
    int** droveCar;
    int currentCar[2];
} Car;

int init(struct Car *cars, int argc, char** argv ) {
    int i, j;

    cars = malloc (3 * sizeof(struct Car));

    for (i = 0 ; i < numberCar ; i++) {
        droveCar[i]=malloc(10 * sizeof(int));
    }

    for (j = 0; j < numberCar; i++) {
        cars[i].droveCar = (int**) malloc(numberCar * sizeof(int*));
    }
}
```

I have also initalised in main:

```
int main() {   
    struct Car *cars;

    /......./

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `typedef struct {` --> `typedef struct Car {` or `struct Car` --> `Car`

Comment: BTW `cars = malloc (3 * sizeof(struct Car));` : this is not rewrite orignal(`struct Car *cars;`).

Comment: not to mention that `numberCar` is not defined in `init` function.

Comment: `droveCar` and `numberCar` are member of `Car`.

Comment: `cars[i].droveCar = (int**) malloc(numberCar * sizeof(int*));` into  i's for-loop.

Comment: `init` not return (int)value.

Comment: so many errors - how would I define numberCar in init? struct Car.numberCar;

Comment: @Sam23yo meaning of `3` What?

Answer (score 0):

Probably, Something like the following

```
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct Car {
    int numberCar;
    int carStatus;
    int** droveCar;
    int currentCar[2];
} Car;

void init(Car *car, int numberCar) {
    int i;

    car->numberCar = numberCar;
    //car->carStatus = 0;
    //car->currentCar[0] = car->currentCar[1] = -1;

    car->droveCar = malloc(numberCar * sizeof(int*));
    for (i = 0 ; i < numberCar ; i++) {
        car->droveCar[i] = calloc(10, sizeof(int));
    }
}

int main() {   
    struct Car *cars;
    int i;

    cars = calloc(3, sizeof(Car));//struct Car cars[3];// 3 Cars
    for(i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
        init(&cars[i], 3);

    //deallocate
    return 0;
}
```